# how do i make a variable that combines two variables?

Tags: java, string, variables, random, int

i tried looking online and did not fined anything helpful, i am making a hangman game, and i want a String that would get a random word from a huge pile of words, i thought that if i made all my words variables like `word1`, and made a String that equals word plus a random integer Ex. `String randomWord = word+randomInt;` then made a random number generator that would generate a random number and set it to randomInt, but when i do that it tells me that word is not a variable, i tried putting ' those things around the whole statement, but it didn't work, how could i do something like this?

CODE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class hangMan {


    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        Random random = new Random();

        int randomInt = random.nextInt(2) + 1;

        System.out.println("Random Integer in Java: " + randomInt);


        //word letters
        final String word1Letter1 = "l";
        final String word1Letter2 = "u";
        final String word1Letter3 = "d";
        final String word1Letter4 = "e";
        final String word1 = "lude";

        final String word2Letter1 = "l";
        final String word2Letter2 = "o";
        final String word2Letter3 = "s";
        final String word2Letter4 = "e";
        final String word2 = "lose";

        final String word3Letter1 = "s";
        final String word3Letter2 = "t";
        final String word3Letter3 = "o";
        final String word3Letter4 = "p";
        final String word3 = "stop";

        //fault counter
        final int faultCounter = 8;

        String randomWord = word+randomInt;

        //looks for the game ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        JFrame hangPanel = new JFrame("Hang Game");
        hangPanel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        hangPanel.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel northContainer = new JPanel();
        northContainer.setVisible(true);
        northContainer.setBackground(Color.gray);

        JPanel southContainer = new JPanel();
        southContainer.setVisible(true);
        southContainer.setBackground(Color.gray);


        final JEditorPane outComunication = new JEditorPane();
        outComunication.setVisible(true);
        outComunication.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        outComunication.setEditable(false);
        outComunication.setSize(300,50);

        final JEditorPane counterOutComunication = new JEditorPane();
        counterOutComunication.setVisible(true);
        counterOutComunication.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        counterOutComunication.setEditable(false);
        counterOutComunication.setSize(90,50);
        counterOutComunication.setText("Tries left: " + faultCounter);


        JPanel wordLayer = new JPanel();
        wordLayer.setVisible(true);
        wordLayer.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        final JTextField wordLayerLetter1 = new JTextField(2);
        wordLayerLetter1.setVisible(true);
        wordLayerLetter1.setEditable(false);

        final JTextField wordLayerLetter2 = new JTextField(2);
        wordLayerLetter2.setVisible(true);
        wordLayerLetter2.setEditable(false);

        final JTextField wordLayerLetter3 = new JTextField(2);
        wordLayerLetter3.setVisible(true);
        wordLayerLetter3.setEditable(false);

        final JTextField wordLayerLetter4 = new JTextField(2);
        wordLayerLetter4.setVisible(true);
        wordLayerLetter4.setEditable(false);

        final JButton nextWord = new JButton("Next Word");
        nextWord.setVisible(false);

        final JTextField guessField = new JTextField(10);
        guessField.setVisible(true);

        //Functionality of the game --------------------------------------------------------------------------

        guessField.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public int innerFaultCounter = faultCounter;
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    String enteredText = guessField.getText();
                    guessField.setEditable(true);

                    if(enteredText.equals(word1Letter1)) 
                    {
                        outComunication.setText("The letter \"" + enteredText + "\" is correct");
                        wordLayerLetter1.setText(word1Letter1);
                        guessField.setText("");

                    } else if(enteredText.equals(word1Letter2)) {
                        outComunication.setText("The letter \"" + enteredText + "\" is correct");
                        wordLayerLetter2.setText(word1Letter2);
                        guessField.setText("");

                    } else if(enteredText.equals(word1Letter3)) {
                        outComunication.setText("The letter \"" + enteredText + "\" is correct");
                        wordLayerLetter3.setText(word1Letter3);
                        guessField.setText("");

                    } else if(enteredText.equals(word1Letter4)) {
                        outComunication.setText("The letter \"" + enteredText + "\" is correct");
                        wordLayerLetter4.setText(word1Letter4);
                        guessField.setText("");

                    } else if(enteredText.equals(word1)) {
                        outComunication.setText("The word \"" + enteredText + "\" is correct");
                        wordLayerLetter1.setText(word1Letter1);
                        wordLayerLetter2.setText(word1Letter2);
                        wordLayerLetter3.setText(word1Letter3);
                        wordLayerLetter4.setText(word1Letter4);
                        guessField.setText("");

                    } else if(enteredText.equals("")) {
                    outComunication.setText("Please type something");
                    guessField.setText("");

                    } else {
                        outComunication.setText("The letter/Word \"" + enteredText + "\" is wrong");
                        guessField.setText("");

                        innerFaultCounter = innerFaultCounter - 1;
                        counterOutComunication.setText("Tries left: " + innerFaultCounter);

                    }

                    //make an if statement that sets the correct word if tries = 0

                    if(innerFaultCounter == 0) {
                        guessField.setEditable(false);

                        nextWord.setVisible(true);
                        innerFaultCounter = faultCounter;
                        counterOutComunication.setText("Tries left: " + innerFaultCounter);
                        outComunication.setText("The correct word is \"" + word1 + "\"");

                    }
                    String letterWordLayerLetter1 = wordLayerLetter1.getText();
                    String letterWordLayerLetter2 = wordLayerLetter2.getText();
                    String letterWordLayerLetter3 = wordLayerLetter3.getText();
                    String letterWordLayerLetter4 = wordLayerLetter4.getText();
                    if(letterWordLayerLetter1.equals(word1Letter1)) {
                        if(letterWordLayerLetter2.equals(word1Letter2)) {
                            if(letterWordLayerLetter3.equals(word1Letter3)) {
                                if(letterWordLayerLetter4.equals(word1Letter4)) {
                                    nextWord.setVisible(true);
                                    guessField.setEditable(false);
                                    innerFaultCounter = faultCounter;
                                    counterOutComunication.setText("Tries left: " + innerFaultCounter);
                                    outComunication.setText("The word \"" + word1 + "\" is correct");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            );

        nextWord.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                guessField.setEditable(true);
                nextWord.setVisible(false);
                wordLayerLetter1.setText("");
                wordLayerLetter2.setText("");
                wordLayerLetter3.setText("");
                wordLayerLetter4.setText("");
                outComunication.setText("");
            }
        }
        );


        //Sorting the pecies of the program intothe display

        wordLayer.add(wordLayerLetter1);
        wordLayer.add(wordLayerLetter2);
        wordLayer.add(wordLayerLetter3);
        wordLayer.add(wordLayerLetter4);
        wordLayer.add(nextWord);

        northContainer.add(guessField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        northContainer.add(wordLayer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        southContainer.add(outComunication, BorderLayout.EAST);
        southContainer.add(counterOutComunication, BorderLayout.WEST);

        hangPanel.add(southContainer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        hangPanel.add(northContainer, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        hangPanel.pack();
        hangPanel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

now the only part that is relavent is the first bunch of lines, the rest is the whole game functionality, i didnt set the if statements in the `actionListener` to `randomWord`, because i will not do it until `randomWord` works properlly, how could i work around this?

Comment: `now the only part that is relavent is the first bunch of lines`...

Comment: Oh boy it's time to learn about `arrays`.

Comment: well i guess time to open up the programmers best friend, the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code seen below won't compile is because you've never created any Object named `word`.

```
String word = "someRandomWordHere";
String randomWord = word + randomInt;
```

Here's how you could tackle this problem:

```
1.) Turn your 3 final word variables into arrays.
2.) Loop through the arrays.
3.) Implement random in such a way that it picks one of the 3 words you've specified.
4.) Set your randomWord equal to the newly randomized word.
5.) Continue
```

EDIT:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random r = new Random();
    int randomInt = r.nextInt(3);

    String words[] = { "lude", "lose", "stop" };
    String randomWord = words[randomInt];

    System.out.println(randomWord);
}
```

Comment: i just did that and set the object word, to "word", but that prints out word1, or whatever random number, i want it to call the object word1 which would be lude

Comment: sorry, that comment was before you edited your answer.

Comment: @yoseph1998 Also, look into the `charAt(Index)` method in the String class. It gives you access to a specific character in a String. Might help you do your comparisons for single letters.

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] myWords = { "alpha", "beta", "meringue" };

String randomWord = myWords[random.nextInt(myWords.length)];
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure

Comment: ok there is another problem, thats the word, but for each word there are 4 letters, and when i person enters a letter in the text field, then it checks the letter, wich would be word1Letter1. this only works if they guess the whole word.

Comment: You can use `randomWord.contains(...)` to see if the word contains a given letter. You can use `randomWord.charAt(i)` to see what the letter is in a given position. Having each letter in a separate variable is a waste of effort. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

you should put all your words inside an array like this:

```
 String words = {"word1","word2","word3"};
```

Create a random generator object

```
Random randomWordGenerator = new Random();
```

And whenever you want to get a random word just generate a random integer and use this value as the index value in the array for the letter like this:

```
int index = randomWordGenerator.nextInt(words.length);
```

And now this should give you a random word:

```
String randomWord = words[index];
```